# Checking if user submitted the correct answer

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 4 tables:

```
        `users`
+---------+--------+
|    id   | name   | 
+---------+--------+
|       1 |   John |
|       3 |   Sam  |
|       4 |   Doe  | 
+---------+--------+


   `questions`
+---------+------------+
|    id   | question   | 
+---------+------------+
|       1 |   Qe1      |
|       3 |   Qe2      |
|       4 |   Qe3      | 
+---------+------------+



                      `answers`
+---------+--------+-------------+--------------+
|    id   | answer | is_correct  | question_id  |
+---------+--------+-------------+--------------+
|       1 |   1234 |      0      |       1      |
|       3 |   2233 |      1      |       1      |
|       4 |   88   |      0      |       1      |
+---------+--------+-------------+--------------+

     
         `user_answers`

+---------+--------+---------+--------------+
|    id   | answer | user_id | question_id  |
+---------+--------+---------+--------------+
|       1 |   2514 |     1   |      1       |
|       2 |        |     1   |      2       |
|       3 |   8785 |     1   |      3       |
|       4 |    579 |     1   |      4       |
+---------+--------+---------+--------------+
```

I'm trying to fetch the `name` from `users` table. As well as `is_correct` from the `user_answers` table

My query:

```
SELECT c.name, GROUP_CONCAT(a.is_correct) AS correct
FROM user_answers ua 
JOIN users u 
ON u.id = ua.user_id
JOIN answers a
ON a.answer = ua.answer 
GROUP BY u.id;
```

There are 50 answers. But for some users, I get like 51 from `GROUP_CONCAT` and it should be 50.

The `answer` in `user_answers` could be empty, doesn't exist or exists.
So:

- if `ua.answer` == `a.answer`, `1` or `0` returned.
- if `ua.answer` != `a.answer`, `0` returned.
- if `ua.answer` == '', `0` returned.

So the output will look like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => John
            [correct] => 0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Sam
            [correct] => 1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
        )

)
```

Comment: The table relationships are confusing.  Why is `is_correct` a property of `answers` - instead of a user's answer? Why doesn't `user answers` store the PK of the `answer` table? Since unlike a PK, an answer "value" may not be unique, that may be why you're seeing duplicates.

Comment: *"...As well as is_correct from the user_answers table....."*  The column "is_correct" isn't stored in the `user_answers` table in your DDL. It's a column in the `answers` table.

Comment: @SOS Because there are multiple answers. If the user for example enters `123` as a value, How would I know if it's the correct one?

Comment: @SOS If I store add column `is_correct` to answers, How could I check it's the right answer or not to enter a value for `is_correct`?

Comment: `If the user for example enters 123 as a value....`  How do you know what question the user is even answering when they enter 123?

Comment: If the answers table contains multiple rows with a *value* of 123, there's no way to identify a single "answer" that matches the user entry. The query will return multiple rows for a single entry, which is probably why you're seeing duplicates. Still seems like there's a relationship missing...

Comment: @SOS There is a table for questions. But I thought it's not needed as I just want to check the correct answer

Comment: I updated the question with the 4th table

Comment: `But I thought it's not needed` The question table isn't needed, but the question_id columns are. Without them, there's no relationship between the other tables. Anyway, it makes more sense now.  I have to head out for a while, but try this https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3659b296dd511b3af13e7d473c32d5d3  . Note, the sample data doesn't contain entries for answers, so some of the results are just "0".